# JavaScript: Splitting a string without splitting a substring

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have a string that looks like this:

```
var str = "'1vK3KfqgSHqv5Y0066FnIY',#41,$,$,(#149,#488,#862,#945,#1028,#1249),#114";
```

Usually I would just:

```
str.split(",");
```

But this will result in:

```
[
    "'1vK3KfqgSHqv5Y0066FnIY'", 
    "#41", 
    "$", 
    "$", 
    "(#149", 
    "#488", 
    "#862", 
    "#945", 
    "#1028", 
    "#1249)", 
    "#114"
]
```

Whereas the desired result is:

```
[
    "'1vK3KfqgSHqv5Y0066FnIY'", 
    "#41", 
    "$", 
    "$", 
    "(#149, #488, #862, #945, #1028, #1249)", 
    "#114"
]
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: what if the string would be `"'1vK3KfqgSHqv5Y0066FnIY',(#1,(#41,$),$,(#149,#488,#862,#945,#1028,#1249),#11),#114"` ? How should look the expected result?

Comment: You'd need to write some sort of  customer parser to account for parentheses.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest In that case it would be an array consisting of 3 records: 
[
"'1vK3KfqgSHqv5Y0066FnIY'",
"(#1,(#41,$),$,(#149,#488,#862,#945,#1028,#1249),#11)",‌
‌​"#114"
]

But I do not think the IFC STEP file (which this is based on) has that kind of structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi here would be a regex

```
str.match(/(\(.*?\)|[^\(,\s]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g)
```

which results in

```
[ '\'1vK3KfqgSHqv5Y0066FnIY\'',
  '#41',
  '$',
  '$',
  '(#149,#488,#862,#945,#1028,#1249)',
  '#114' ]
```

Comment: Provide demo to checking result.

Comment: Seems not everything had been copied right to Regexr, now it works. Thanks!